# Vue authentication

Tags: vue.js, authentication, router

I am building this small app with Vue,And I can't make the authentication work.To be exact,the redirect does not work,I get both the true and the Authenticated logs but I am not getting redirected to the home page (/).But when I turn on the app I get instantly taken to /login which that is ok and I want that,but as I said when i try to log in I am not getting redirected

here is my login component and my router.

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import LoginView from '@/views/LoginView.vue'
import AboutView from '../views/AboutView.vue';
import  isAuthenticated  from '@/views/LoginView.vue'; 

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/login',
      name: 'Login',
      component: LoginView
    },
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Home',
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: true
      },
  
      component: AboutView,
      beforeEnter:(to,_,next)=>{
        if(to.meta.requiresAuth && !isAuthenticated.value){
          next('/login');
        }
        else{
          next();
          router.push('/');
        }
      }
     
    }
  ]
})

export default router
```

```
<template>
<div>
    <h2>Enter the access token to login</h2>

    <hr />
    
    <div class="col-md-8">

        <section id="loginForm">

            <form @submit.prevent="checkAccessToken">
                <div class="form-group">

                    <label><b>Access Token</b></label>
                    <input v-model="accessToken" type="password" class="form-control" />

                </div>
                
                <input  type="submit" value="Log in"  class="btn btn-primary" />

            </form>
        </section>

    </div>
   
</div> 

</template>
<script setup lang="ts">

import { ref} from 'vue'

import router  from '@/router/index'

const isAuthenticated = ref(false);

const accessToken = ref('');

const checkAccessToken = () => {
  if (accessToken.value === '123') {
      isAuthenticated.value = true;
      console.log(isAuthenticated.value);
      console.log('Authenticated');
      router.push('/');
  } else {
  }
};


</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If only the `router.push()` is not working

how about vue-router import like

```
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router'
const router = useRouter();
```

and use `router.push('/')`

Comment: It still doesnt work :(

Comment: how about just nest() in beforeEnter
 beforeEnter:(to,_,next)=>{
        if(to.meta.requiresAuth && !isAuthenticated.value){
          next('/login');
        }
        else{
          next();
        }
      }

Comment: thanks a lot buddy the guard was causing the problem